# What is the easiest way to stop and start services on a remote and virtual Windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows, services

On a computer a virtual instance of windows 7 is running. From a remote location I want to be able to stop and start services on this virtual instance of windows 7, given the IP address.

What is the EASIEST way to do this? There is no need to worry about any security issues! I am interested about the EASIEST and QUICKEST way to achieve this goal!

P.S. I have admin rights on both machines.

Comment: Please clarify that you only have local admin accounts, since the easiest way for a domain admin is grawity's solution, not yours. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this goal might be to install [PsTools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) and use the `PsService` command like:

```
./PsService.exe \\172.16.4.154 -u username -p password stop "name of service"
```

On the remote machine a service named `Remote Registry` must run in order to use the `PsTools`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `sc`:

```
sc \\1.2.3.4 query Foo
sc \\1.2.3.4 qc Foo
sc \\1.2.3.4 config Foo start= demand
sc \\1.2.3.4 start Foo
```

Comment: I get the following error: [SC] StartService: OpenService FAILED 1060:

The specified service does not exist as an installed service.

Comment: @Alex: That might be because you got the name wrong, or because the service really doesn't exist. (`sc` wants the real name like LmServer, not the "display name". Run `sc query`.)

Comment: I tried `sc \\172.16.4.154 stop "PNC - Pnms"` to stop the existing service on the remote machine, but got the following error (in German): `Set-Content : Es wurde kein Positionsparameter gefunden, der das Argument "PNC - Pnms" akzeptiert.
Bei Zeile:1 Zeichen:3
+ sc <<<<  \\172.16.4.154 stop "PNC - Pnms"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Content], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand`

Comment: @Alex: Ah, it seems PowerShell overrides `sc` with an internal command. Try `sc.exe \\172.16.4.154` instead.

Comment: Then I get an 'access denied' error (OpenSCManager ERROR 5)

Comment: @Alex: Try starting with `sc.exe \\172.16.4.154 query` to get a list of services. find the right one and copy the SERVICE_NAME not the DISPLAY_NAME. Make sure your PS runs as admin, i get a different error for misspelled service names: "... FEHLER 1060: Der angegebene Dienst ist kein installierter Dienst."

Comment: @TheUser: Using `sc.exe \\172.16.4.154 query` inside an administrator powershell I get the same access-denied error as before.

Comment: @Alex local admin on your machine or domain admin?

Comment: @TheUser: local admin. I guess I need to configure the remote machine to accept a 'sc' command from a different machine. How to do that?

Comment: The _local_ privileges don't matter at all, only the ones that the _remote_ machine gives, since you're controlling the _remote_ machine after all. It could be that you're hitting the [remote UAC restrictions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951016).